# returning data from for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, callback, socket.io, return

i am using socket.io to fetch data about a user using his uid when you run this function

```
function getUserData(uid){
    "use strict"
    socket.emit('getUserData',uid, function(callback){
        console.log('callback' + callback)
        for (var i = 0; i < callback.length; i++) {
            var row = callback[i];
            var username = row.username;
            var about = row.about;
            var uid = row.uid;
        }
    })        
    return {
                username:  username,
                uid: uid,
             //   about: about
            };
}
```

and it does this on the server side

```
socket.on('getUserData',function(uid, callback){
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = ?', [uid], function(err, rows) {
        callback(rows)
    })
})
```

but when i do `console.log(getUserData(uid))` i get undefined but i do get the object from the first callback what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: This question really doesn't make sense for several reasons.  First, you're running a `for` loop and then trying to return something from it?  Why iterate the whole loop if you only want to return one value.  Second, you're getting an asynchronous callback.  You can't EVER return data from that.  Your host function returns LONG before that callback is called.  Your `getUserData()` function is asynchronous.  It has to return the value asynchronously, either via a callback or promise.

Comment: so there is no way i can grab the data from that for loop and return it i'm new to using callbacks and returns sorry

Comment: Nope, it's a matter of timing. Your function `getUserData()` returns before you get the data back from the socket.  See my answer for one option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback from `.emit()` is asynchronous.  That means it happens sometime LATER, long after your `getUserData()` function has already returned.  That means you have to communicate back the result using either a callback or a promise.  In addition, it makes no sense that you're trying to iterate an array and return one result.  You should either return all the results or pick one particular item from the array as your final value.  This resolves with the whole array of data, letting the caller decide which one they want to pick from the array.

Here's how you could do so with a promise:

```
function getUserData(uid){
    "use strict"
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        socket.emit('getUserData',uid, function(returnData){
            console.log('returnData', returnData)
            resolve(returnData);
        });
    });
}

// usage
getUserData(someUID).then(results => {
    // use results in here
});
```